# EC2 cloudformation template using conditions to add ebs volume

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to add EBS Volume to my EC2 resource based on a condition of EBS volume required or not. How can I make the condition work?
Here is the snippet of code:

```
Conditions:
  EbsVolumeTrue: !Equals [!Ref EBS, true]
Resources:
  Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-xxxxxx
      !If [EbsVolumeTrue, !Ref BlockDeviceMappings, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
      BlockDeviceMappings: 
       - DeviceName: !Ref VolumeName
         Ebs: 
           VolumeType: !Ref VolumeType
           DeleteOnTermination: false
           VolumeSize: !Ref VolumeSize
```

Comment: What is `BlockDeviceMappings`?

Comment: The [Condition Functions - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html) page shows examples of whether or not to create a resource using `Condition`, and it shows how to select a value using `!If`, but I don't think you can include/exclude parameters in the way you have shown. You _might_ need to create two `Instance` resources (one with a disk, one without), and give them different conditions so that only one gets created. (But I haven't tried anything like that.)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to go with  multiple lines in Conditions:

```
Conditions:
  EbsVolumeTrue: !Equals [!Ref EBS, true]
Resources:
  Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-xxxxxx
      Fn::If:
        - EbsVolumeTrue
        - 
          BlockDeviceMappings: 
          - DeviceName: !Ref VolumeName
            Ebs: 
              VolumeType: !Ref VolumeType
              DeleteOnTermination: false
              VolumeSize: !Ref VolumeSize
        - Ref: AWS::NoValue
```